# send formdata file and string to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How can I send string to PHP using Ajax form data?

This is the current code I found at
https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/File-Upload-Progress-Bar-Meter-Tutorial-Ajax-PHP.

How can I pass string to PHP using the code below? I want to implement that code to my website, because I need to upload the image with a progressbar to know if the file is uploaded successfully by the user.

I want to pass the name of the image to the PHP.

```
function uploadFile(){
    var file = _("file1").files[0];
    // alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("file1", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "file_upload_parser.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
```

I know how to pass string to PHP using Ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "phpfile.php",
    data: ({data1: "data1").value})
    })
```

But I want to implement the code from the website above. Thank you.

Comment: append new key/value to `formdata`

Comment: ^ `formdata.append('filename', file.name);`

Comment: if i try something like this, var formdata = new FormData();
 formdata.append("file1", file);
 formData.append('key2', 'value2');

it says formData is not defined

Answer (score -1):

You need to stingify the object before sending..

```
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url :"url",
dataType: "json",
headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},
data: JSON.stringify({"data1": "data1"}),
success: function(data) {

},
error:function(exception){
 }
});
```

Comment: This will not work for file uploads and does not answer the question